# What is the best way to represent honeycomb lattice?

Tags: python, data-structures, logic, mathematical-lattices

I am trying to simulate a honeycomb lattice, I.e, each particle interacts with each of it's 3 neighbors. I want to represent in array such that it is automated. I.e, if any atom is picked at random, code should evaluate some parameter based on connected neighbors.

[image: honeycomb lattice]

I can think of it in this way:

1. initialize n*n array.
2. every particle interacts with particles next to it on right and left sides
3. particle on odd row and odd column interact with it's bottom particle
4. particle on odd row and even column interact with it's top particle
5. particle on even row and odd column interact with it's top particle
6. particle on even row and even column interact with it's bottom particle

The equivalence is shown below in the pictures.

[image: Actual honeycomb lattice]

[image: restructured structure which can be represented by arrows]

Is there a better method to represent the same?

Comment: Maybe this helps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70294413/coordinates-of-the-edges-of-a-honeycomb-grid-in-python?noredirect=1#comment124262783_70294413

Answer (score 2):

There is a reference here that might be of use:

https://homepages.inf.ed.ac.uk/rbf/CVonline/LOCAL_COPIES/AV0405/MARTIN/Hex.pdf

Also, there is a SE answer that might be of help:

[Generate, fill and plot a hexagonal lattice in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27108292/generate-fill-and-plot-a-hexagonal-lattice-in-python)

Also, this:

https://www.redblobgames.com/grids/hexagons/

Comment: The paper talks about representing hexagonal system(6 neighbors) where as my problem is honeycomb system(3 neighbors). Thanks for your efforts though

Comment: Ah, I see - I think there is some relation. One comment made about the hexagonal option is that shoehorning to a rectangular grid could be non-ideal.  An interesting question.

Comment: BTW, when you find a solution, post it here.  I think this will be of interest to users.